How do I edit my postgresql.conf file without starting the docker container in which it resides? I currently have a fatal error caused postgresql.conf
I'm trying to edit my postgresql.conf file so I can restart my docker container. Currently my docker container running postgres immediately fails because of this error, but I can't fix the error because I need the docker container to be running in order to reach it.
database system is shut down

PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization

2024-09-07 00:10:26.465 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not load server certificate file "/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt": No such file or directory
2024-09-07 00:10:26.465 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down

I've tried to reach the files through the docker desktop app, but it says the container needs to be started in order to reach the files.

Does How to edit files in stopped/not starting docker container answer your question?  That has a recipe using docker cp, which should work on the stopped container.  Depending on where the relevant configuration file actually is (is it bind-mounted from the host, or automatically generated on startup?) you may also be able to delete and recreate the container, which is a pretty routine operation.
